# Docker with npm install adds unwanted symlink

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I'm trying to build a nodejs container for my project which requires a local module. On my package.json i got a relative link to a folder above, since there is where the local module is located. Everything seems to work correctly except that inside the container, the local module is added as symlink to the host machine (windows).

This behavior only happens when i build using the dockerfile, if i do npm install manually inside the container, the module is copied into the node_module as expected.

package.json entry:

```
"app-lib": "file:../app_lib"
```

docker file:

```
FROM node:8.9-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["./Provider/package.json", "./Provider/package-lock.json*", "./Provider/npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "./"]
COPY ["./app_lib/package.json", "./app_lib/package-lock.json*", "./app_lib/npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "../app_lib/"]
RUN cd ../app_lib && npm install
COPY ./app_lib .
RUN cd ../app && npm install
COPY ./Provider .
EXPOSE 3001
```

Annoying symlink:

```
app-lib -> E:\work\app_server\app_lib\
```

Anyone got any suggestion on how to make it work right on build or why might be the underlying cause?

Comment: oh, before i forget, already tried --no-bin-link and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: do you have `node_modules` in `.dockerignore`? Else `COPY ./app_lib .` will overwrite the same

Comment: that was it.. i had node_modules in the .dockerignore but kept didn't realized it was missing the "**/"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have `node_modules` in `.dockerignore`, else `COPY ./app_lib .` will overwrite the same and you will get the behaviour you see

Comment: If anyone bumps into this, like commented above, check for the "**/" to ignore on all subfolders, since that was the main culprit.

Comment: So you made 2 entries? or `node_modules/**/`?

Comment: i made `**/node_modules` to include all directory with that any in any sub-directory.